# How to add Hotword Detection in python AI

Tags: python, speech-recognition

I am trying to make a python AI using the `speech_recognition` module,
and i want to add a hotword detection feature in the AI, so I tried to make it using `speech_recognition` module but it didn't work. It listened once after 4 - 5 seconds and started recognizing the things spoken. Therefor if I speak the `hotword` after the 4-5 second timeframe, it doesn't recognize the `hotword`.

Comment: i am using windows

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `pause_threshold` like

```
import speech_recognition as sr
hot_word='Hi'
r=sr.Recognizer()
r.pause_threshold=5#This waits for 5 sec after voice ends
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    text=r.listen(source)
text=r.recognize_google(text)
if hot_word in text:
    #do anything like calling a function or reply to it
```

Thank you
Have a good day
-Lever